# Scala Lift - Save file from post data (valums uploader)

Tags: scala, lift, ajax-upload

I have the following object

```
object Upload_Dispatch extends RestHelper {

    serve {

        /* Presentation ---------------------------------------------*/
        case "upload_presentation" :: Nil Post req => {

            println(req.body.map(_.length))

            JsonResponse(JObject(JField("success", JBool(true)) :: Nil))

        }

    }

}
```

This comes from here:

https://github.com/timperrett/lift-file-uploader

The valums uploader script is here:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

I've got the whole thing working ok with the response returned etc, how do I actually save the files that are being sent? How do I access the actual byte array so I can use FileOutputStream?

Thanks in advance, any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can adjust the code form [here](https://github.com/lunserv/lift_ajax_fileupload/blob/master/src/main/scala/code/lib/UploadManager.scala) to get your file upload save the files to your server.
That  example saves it to MongoFS.

[This one](https://github.com/fmpwizard/lift_fileupload/blob/master/src/main/scala/code/snippet/upload.scala) saves it to the disk